Visual Studio C# (.NET Core 6): Text and UI Elements Pixelated, Not Smooth (ugly)
I have been experiencing this issue for a long time and have tried everything I could think of to resolve it. In Visual Studio C# (.NET Core 6), the text and UI elements are consistently pixelated and not smooth. The borders of the elements are pixelated, and the colors seem to be missing in some areas. This issue is not limited to buttons but affects all text and UI elements.
I've attempted various solutions, including adjusting display settings, updating drivers, and reinstalling Visual Studio, but nothing has resolved the problem. The pixelation affects the overall readability and aesthetics of the UI, making it quite frustrating to work with.
Has anyone else encountered this issue, and if so, what steps did you take to fix it? Any help would be greatly appreciated.
This text outlines the problem clearly, mentions the steps you've already taken, and asks for help from others who might have experienced the same issue.
[[Picture1] [[Picture2] [[Picture3
I've tried several troubleshooting steps but none of them works.

Displays only have so many pixels, you'll have to be more specific about what you expect.

I think we could try to narrow down the issue first, whether it's a device issue(the screen) or code issue. If it's code issue, we might try to compare the problematic page and a no-issue page.

Could you please let us know what does the content in the screenshot looks like in your screen? https://i.sstatic.net/f7Y2XM6t.png    The screenshot I take from a default .Net 6 MVC application.

Looks normal for me

Could you please share a minimal sample with us? It mighjt related with CSS
